# R use the symbol Angstroms in xlabel

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, symbols

I am using **ggplot2** and `facet_grid`, and the output format is PNG. How can I write the symbol "Angstroms" in the x-axis label? I tried `xlab("{\305}")` but that printed a weird symbol for me.

Comment: Try `xlab("\uc5")` or `xlab("\u212b")`

Answer (score 2):

There is a list of different solutions. Some may not work for particular task.

```
xlab="\u5c"
xlab="\u212b"
xlab="Å"
```

work in R session (but not for PDF output).

```
xlab=expression(ring(A) )
```

works both in R session and for PDF output.